# Trying to pull data from a json/api instead of an array

Tags: arrays, json, angular, api, http

I have a project that is using an array of data but I want to be able to access external data such as a JSON file or an API with it instead of hardcoding it into the project. I added a http get request to pull the JSON file in but if I change the Observable from `this.arrayData` to `this.jsonData` nothing shows up. Would anybody be able to help me out?

**app.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    Rx.Observable.from(this.arrayData[0].data)
      .groupBy(x => x.customer.name) // using groupBy from Rxjs
      .flatMap(group => group.toArray()) // GroupBy doesn't create an array object so you have to flat it
      .map(g => {
        // mapping
        return {
          name: g[0].customer.name, //take the first name because we grouped them by name
          price: _.sumBy(g, "billing_stage_net_value") // using lodash to sum price
        };
      })
      .toArray() //.toArray so that you can loop on it with ngFor
      .do(sum => console.log("sum:", sum)) // just for debug
      .subscribe(d => (this.groupedArrayData = d));

// pull from Json
    this.jsonData = this.http
      .get("assets/transactions.json")
      .map(data => _.values(data))
      .do(console.log);
  }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody *ngFor="let data of groupedArrayData">
        <tr>
            <td>{{data.name}}</td>
            <td>€{{data.price}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**transactions.json (same data that is in the array)**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "billing_stage_net_value": 15.160000000000,
      "customer": {
        "name": "Harbour Cafe"
      },
      "id": 1142,
      "transaction_date": "2019-10-22T13:56:11.971643+00:00"
    },
    {
      "billing_stage_net_value": 51.000000000000,
      "customer": {
        "name": "Crisp Sandwich Cafe"
      },
      "id": 1143,
      "transaction_date": "2019-10-22T13:57:24.375087+00:00"
    },
    {
      "billing_stage_net_value": 13.500000000000,
      "customer": {
        "name": "Crisp Sandwich Cafe"
      },
      "id": 1144,
      "transaction_date": "2019-10-22T13:57:24.375087+00:00"
    }
  ],
  "message": "",
  "metadata": {},
  "success": true
}
```

Comment: can you try to include a working stackblitz demo

Comment: Sure, here you go: https://stackblitz.com/edit/groupby-with-sum-array?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: if you're not using async pipe, you **need** subscribe to http.get (equal you subscribe to the `Rx.Observable.from(...)`.e.g. `http.get(...).subscribe(res=>this.groupedArrayData=res)` BTW, why use the "old" angular 5?

Comment: I tried dding that right after the http.get but I get errors on the `.map` and `.do` functions. Should I have `.subscribe` at the very end? The project is currently on Angular 7.